# kubuntu Edit Window Decorations

Tags: kubuntu, customization, window-decoration

I am trying to make my desktop install match my laptop, so I want to use the same themes and decoration settings. However, the decorations that I am using (BreezeMite Dark) for some reason makes the title bar of the application shorter than the window on the desktop, I am hoping there is a way to edit the files to correct this.

Answer (score 0):

You can change font size on window title (system settings -> fonts) and title bar will adjust itseft accordingly.

I could not find any uncompiled files containing window decorations, so I am not sure if these are just config files to edit.